# django ratings app , negative scoring

Tags: django, django-models, django-apps

## models.py

```
class Restaurant(models.Model)
    food_rating = RatingField(range=2, weight=5,can_change_vote = True,allow_delete = True,allow_anonymous = True)
    service_rating = RatingField(range=2, weight=5,can_change_vote = True,allow_delete = True,allow_anonymous = True)
    ambience_ratiing = RatingField(range=2, weight=5,can_change_vote = True,allow_delete = True,allow_anonymous = True)
```

## view.py code

```
r = Restaurant.objects.get(pk=1)
r.food_rating.add(score = -1 , user = request.user , ip_address =request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
print r.food_rating.score
```

## error

```
djangoratings.exceptions.InvalidRating: -1 is not a valid choice for food_rating
```

## doubt

my food_rating field is eligible to take two scores , how am i supposed to change the score so that i can implement vote up and vote down feature , on vote up , i should be able to add 1 to the existing score and on vote down i should be able to subtract a vote , please help , thanks in advance

Comment: Is RatingField a custom field?

Comment: i am using djangoratings application , https://github.com/dcramer/django-ratings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from [this script](https://github.com/dcramer/django-ratings/blob/master/djangoratings/fields.py#L141):

```
if score < 0 or score > self.field.range:
    raise InvalidRating("%s is not a valid choice for %s" % (score, self.field.name))
```

Short answer: convert the [-x:y] interval you want to use for display, into [-x+x:y+x] in your code to avoid this problem. If you wanted [-5:5], then use [-5+5:5+5] which is [0:10]. If you wanted [-50:100] then use [-50+50:100+50] = [0:150] and so on ... It's a simple formula, that shouldn't be a problem for a programer ;)

Long answer: either you fork djangoratings, either you open an issue asking to add a setting enabling negative ratings ... and probably he'll reject it, because of the simple interval conversion workaround, here's some more concrete examples:

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    # blabla :)

    ambience_rating = RatingField(range=5, weight=5,can_change_vote = True,allow_delete = True,allow_anonymous = True)

    def get_adjusted_ambiance_rating(self):
        return self.ambience_rating - 3
```

So, if ambience_rating is "1" (the lowest score), get_adjusted_ambiance_rating() will return -2.

If ambience_rating is "5" (the highest score), get_ambiance_rating_with_negative() will return 2.

Adapt this example/trick to your needs.

You should probably make a single method for all ratings:

```
def get_adjusted_rating(self, which):
    return getattr(self, '%s_rating' % which) - 3
```

Callable as such:

```
restaurant.get_adjusted_rating('ambiance')
restaurant.get_adjusted_rating('food')

# etc ...
```

And maybe a template filter:

```
@register.filter
def get_adjusted_rating(restaurant, which):
    return restaurant.get_adjusted_rating(which)
```

Usable as such:

```
{{ restaurant|get_adjusted_rating:"ambiance" }}
{{ restaurant|get_adjusted_rating:"food" }}

{# etc, etc #}
```

More [details about template filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#).

Comment: thanks but i wanted to vote down as in , user should have option to  vote down or vote negatively

Comment: Easy, do as such: vote super down -> 1, vote down -> 2, vote neutral -> 3, vote up -> 4, vote super up -> 5. Keep the 1-5 range in your code, but in templates use the converted value... do you understand ?

Comment: Added technical details to answer.

Comment: yea exactly but i ll just keep the 2 values , 1 would be like and 2 would be dislike , thanks